# How to call a function bundled with webpack with external javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, frontend

How to call a function bundled with webpack with external javascript?

The webpack.js file consists of:

```
const init = (inputUrl) => {
    // window.onload = function(){
    init.loadMap = function(inputUrl){
        const wrap = document.querySelector('#px');
        Px.Core.Initialize(wrap, function(){
          Px.Loader.LoadFbx({
          // url: '../src/model/Bumma_004/Bumma_004.FBX',
          url: inputUrl,
            onLoad: function(){
              console.log("FBX Loading Complete");
              console.log(inputUrl);
            }
          })
        })
    }
    init.getconfig = function getconfig(){
        return url;
    }
    // init.getconfig = getconfig;

    function test(msg){
        return console.log('test function completed ' + msg);
    }
    init.test = test;
// }
}
export default init;
```

The index.js file is composed as follows.

```
import init from './temp.js'

init.loadMap('abc');
```

After bundling webpack.js, I want to put another url in index.js in init.loadMap and output to html.

However, in the index.js file, `Cannot use import statement outside a module` occurs on the first line.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using `global.init = init`